# Overriding validation in Breezejs

Tags: c#, breeze

Here is an interesting requirement.  How would I solve this with Breezejs?

(note, using a SPA design based on and extremely similar to the one in John Papa's Angular + Breezejs Pluralsight course)

We have a business rule that says that when I add or edit customer phone number, I need to check the phone number to see if there is a different customer with the same number (can happen due to phone number reassignment, etc).

If I find that it is a dup, I need to prompt the user.  The user has the option to say "yah, that's fine", and then the phone number will save anyway.

So, I get how to do a basic validation with BeforeSaveEntity, and to fail if I find the dup, but suppose the user checks the "save anyway" option.  How do I include this "out of band", non-data row information in my save set so that I can override the server-side validation rule?

And also, I don't want this validation to look like a "normal" error to the user on save -- I want to detect that it was the phone number clash thing, so I can display the view that prompts them to override.

Comment: Note: I know that I could make multiple calls (call the dup check API on save, then save only if the dup check passes), but I'd rather use a "chunky" call so that the save experience is fast as possible when there is not a clash.

Answer (score 2):

Out of band data can be passed either by using the SaveOptions.tag property or by going to a separate named endpoint in your save call. i.e.

```
   var so = new SaveOptions({ tag: "Special kind of save with extra data" });
   return myEntityManager.saveChanges(null, so);
```

or

```
   var so = new SaveOptions({ resourceName: "SaveWithSpecialValidation", tag: "any special data" });
   return em.saveChanges(null, so);
```

In terms of how to return a special server side save validation

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveWithSpecialValidation(JObject saveBundle) {
  // custom tag passed from the client
  var theTag = ContextProvider.SaveOptions.Tag;
  ContextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate = BeforeSaveWithException;
  return ContextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}

private Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveWithException(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap) {
  List<EntityInfo> orderInfos;
  if (saveMap.TryGetValue(typeof(Order), out orderInfos)) {
    if (YourErrorCheckHere(orderInfos)) {
      var errors = orderInfos.Select(oi => {
        return new EFEntityError(oi, "WrongMethod", "My custom exception message",        "OrderID");
      });
      // This is a special exception that will be forwarded correctly back to the client.
      var ex =  new EntityErrorsException("test of custom exception message", errors);
      // if you want to see a different error status code use this.
      // ex.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Conflict; // Conflict = 409 ; default is Forbidden (403).
      throw ex;
    }
  }
  return saveMap;
}
```

Hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you.  1 more question -- building on your last example, what would I need to do on the client side to detect that the failed validation was my special rule (vs. a vanilla one like "this field is required", and that I need to display my confirmation UI?

Comment: Any errors that are returned from the server have an 'isServerError' error property set to true on the client and will also contain whatever error message you have specified. In addition, if the error was associated with a specific entity, as is shown above, then this error will get added to that entity's entityAspect.validationErrors collection ( also with the 'isServerError' property set to true. ).

Comment: For a better user experience, I also recommend a separate async call to the server to check for dup phone numbers so that you can let the user know if there is likely to be a problem before she even tries to save. This would be a non-blocking query, not a validation.